# "Accept-Language" header missing in http request from the browser

Tags: browser

We have come across an issue in production logs where "Accept-Language" is missing in the http request from the browser. Although I am not able to replicate it so I want to understand any valid use case where any specific browser may send a request without "Accept-Language" header.

Answer (score 1):

Even `GET / HTTP/1.0` is a valid HTTP request. You can create one from the telnet client if you wish and it will still return a result from the server!

`Accept-Language` is a header to [aid in content negotiation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Accept-Language) and is optional. The most widely used browsers send the correct headers, but there may be corporate proxies who may be filtering such headers. You should not rely on this header being present.

Comment: Wouldn't a corp proxy that does that just be shooting its users in the foot? By stripping this header they'd prevent employees from reading many sites in their native language. It sounds like the correct answer is, "Yes, there is no valid use case for no Accept-Language header from normal human visitors". Telnet and bots won't, but those require special treatment anyway - and Accept-Language missing is a great giveaway this is a bot/telnet.

Comment: Google crawlers don't send Accept-Language header.